# How to solve "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed." while save operation?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to insert data to a table which has a relation with other table which in turn related to another table. While trying to insert the data to table I am getting an exception

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Code:

```
    using (var transaction = _crmContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
           {
             if (primaryPersonContact.Id > 0)
                    {
                        _crmContext.Entry(primaryPersonContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        customer.Person.Contact2 = _crmContext.Set<Contact>().Add(customer.Person.Contact2);
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
if (primaryPersonContact.Id > 0)
                    {
                        _context.Entry(primaryPersonContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        //_crmContext.Entry(customer.Person.Contact2).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        primaryPersonContact = _crmContext.Set<Contact>().Add(primaryPersonContact);
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                        if (primaryContactPerson.Id > 0)
                    {
                        _crmContext.Entry(primaryContactPerson).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        primaryContactPerson.PrimaryContact = primaryPersonContact.Id;// to insert contact table Id to person Table.
                        primaryContactPerson = _crmContext.Set<Person>().Add(primaryContactPerson);
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    if (customer.Id > 0)
                    {
                        _crmContext.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        customer.CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid();
                        customer.PrimaryContact = primaryContactPerson.Id; //To insert primary contact person Id to customer table.
                        customer = _crmContext.Set<Customer>().Add(customer);
                        await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
```

The error occurs on the line

```
await _crmContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the name I'm guessing that `_crmContext` is a class field and you're reusing it in more than one place.  If you dispose of it in any of those places then that would explain the issue.  In general it's best to create a context (in a using) for a single transaction versus keeping it around for long periods of time.

Comment: @juharr I am using the above code within the `using ` only. Sorry that I missed it out. Actually these three tables are related hence I have kept in single transaction. Is n't this way it is supposed to be?